# Xcode how do I preload relational data in Core Data?

Tags: xcode, core-data

I am working on an app that has a fair amount of information that needs to be preloaded. I have some of the information I need to be able to preload the data, but I don't know how to get the rest of the relational data to be included.

Here is the code I have

```
func preloadData() {

    let fetch: NSFetchRequest<Season> = Season.fetchRequest()
    fetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "searchKey != nil")

    let count = try! managedContext.count(for: fetch)

    if count > 0 { return }

    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Preload", ofType: "plist")

    let dataArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path!)!

    for dict in dataArray {
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Season", in: managedContext)!
        let season = Season(entity: entity, insertInto: managedContext)
        let seasonDict = dict as! [String: Any]
        season.name = seasonDict["name"] as? String
        season.tasks = seasonDict["tasks"] as? NSSet
    }
    try! managedContext.save()
}
```

Here is the data structure:

[image]

How do I include the following in

```
> for dict in dataArray

 - Task > title
 - Task > detail

Here is one <dict> from the <array>

<array>
    <dict>
        <key>season</key>
        <string>Early Winter</string>
        <key>tasks</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>Check water softener and add salt if needed</string>
                <key>details</key>
                <string></string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>Inspect, and change HVAC filters if they are dirty</string>
                <key>details</key>
                <string>If you have no pets or allergies and are a small family, you can change filters only every 2-3 months.</string>
                <key>dueDate</key>
                <string></string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>Clean kitchen sink disposals</string>
                <key>details</key>
                <string>Freeze vinegar in an ice cube tray and run the ice cubes through the disposal to freshen it and sharpen the blades.</string>
                <key>dueDate</key>
                <string></string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>Clean range hood filters</string>
                <key>details</key>
                <string></string>
                <key>dueDate</key>
                <string></string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>Inspect fire extinguishers</string>
                <key>details</key>
                <string>Inspect fire extinguishers to ensure that you can get easy access to them, the gauges show adequate pressure, and they have no visible signs of wear.</string>
                <key>dueDate</key>
                <string></string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
...
</array>
```

Comment: And how do we know what’s in your file?

Comment: Welcome back. I've edited the question to include a sample of the plist data to be imported. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you can get the array from your dictionary using `dict["tasks"]`, then you can iterate over it and create a new Task for each row.

```
for dict in dataArray {
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Season", in: managedContext)!
    let season = Season(entity: entity, insertInto: managedContext)
    let seasonDict = dict as! [String: Any]
    season.name = seasonDict["name"] as? String
    //season.tasks = seasonDict["tasks"] as? NSSet Remove this line
    let tasks = dict["tasks"] //Maybe this should be seasonDict?
    for taskItem in tasks {
        var task = Task(context: managedContext)
        task.title = taskItem.title
        task.details = taskItem.details
        task.parentSeason = season
    }
}
```